# Who makes *FAST* NAS solutions for home/SOHO usage?

Tags: performance, nas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations on a NAS for a home-super-user ?](https://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user)

My basement linux 2.6.28 box (Asus/C2D based) provides a sustained data rate of 116 MB/s over gigabit ethernet when reading from a RAID0 stripe (something *has* happened in newer kernel versions - it used to be 65-70MB/s on older kernels)

I have tried several NAS solutions, and to my amazement they all have lousy performance. I'm still amazed that [reviews](http://reviews.cnet.com/external-hard-drives/seagate-blackarmor-nas-440/4505-3190_7-33573127.html)  (at end of article) can characterize any of the tested NAS'es as FAST. Performance is just about the only requirement I have from a NAS. So what brand/models is the "simplest" I can get away with buying that do not sacrifice performance ? I'm expecting 65MB/s+ performance.

Comment: dupe? http://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user

Comment: duplicity - http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nas

Comment: I cannot see this question as being a duplicate of any of the mentioned questions. How about *reading* my question ?

Comment: Ok, I've voted to re-open, but I'd suggest updating the title to make the difference more clear (e.g. Are there any FAST (>60MB/sec) NAS devices for home usage?).

Comment: On the other hand... the fact that it are devices for HOME usage (meaning being cheap) makes it almost "by definition" less performing. I think you will have to look at professional devices in stead of the consumer ones.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user/9146#9146), I'd recommend a Thecus N4100PRO.

Comment: BUt according to thecus http://www.thecus.com/products_over.php?cid=10&pid=77, this NAS has a whooping 35MB/S throughput ?

Comment: @krosenvold: Well, I haven't got experience with gigabit network at home... only 100 mbit, so data transfer rate is not my priority. I do remember reading somewhere that you can change a setting in the network somewhere to have higher throughput, but I can't find it anymore :-s

Comment: I believe the lousy throughput is related to the low-performance hardware most of these NAS boxes use. That's what my question was about