# Linux on a NAS device

Tags: home-networking, nas, product-rec

I am looking for an inexpensive NAS device that would be able to run a Linux distribution instead of the whatever standard software, so I can set up a simple http server and whatever I will need in the future.

My focus is on price, noise (I am looking for a solution without fans etc.) and low power consumption (I don't need a lot of processor power etc). Would anyone be able to recommend something?

Comment: What's your price range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently bought a [QNAP](http://www.qnap.com/) NAS that I'm happy with. They have a few fanless models (like my TS-119) and it runs some kind of Linux. I don't know exactly what it is, but I know you can install stuff to it through SSH.

It has all the basic stuff, like HTTP and FTP servers, a bittorrent client, MySQL and all kinds of stuff.

Comment: I own a QNAP TS-409 Pro. Fairly inexpensive in comparison to the rest of the market and runs on a custom Linux build. In terms of power, it's fairly efficient but it's hard to compare to other solutions in terms of power as other NASes can use more or less disks.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own and install [FreeNas](http://freenas.org/) on it:

> FreeNAS is a free NAS
>   (Network-Attached Storage) server,
>   supporting: CIFS (samba), FTP, NFS,
>   AFP, RSYNC, iSCSI protocols,
>   S.M.A.R.T., local user authentication,
>   Software RAID (0,1,5) with a Full WEB
>   configuration interface. FreeNAS takes
>   less than 32MB once installed on
>   Compact Flash, hard drive or USB key.
>   The minimal FreeBSD distribution, Web
>   interface, PHP scripts and
>   documentation are based on M0n0wall.

Also, more information about hardware can be found here:

> https://superuser.com/questions/4893/homemade-diy-nas-solution

---

**Update**: I could also recommend you a [Thecus 4100PRO](http://www.thecus.com/products%5Fover.php?cid=10&pid=77) like I also mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user/9146#9146). It runs a [customized linux](http://www.thecus.com/product_firmware.php?cid=10&pid=77&set_language=english) under the hood, and you can run a web server on it. I don't know if it will fit your "inexpensive" requirement though.

Comment: It's probably not going to be the most power efficient option though, and setting up a fanless pc can be both tricky and expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I own an [nslu2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001FSCZO) which fits the bill, except I'm not very happy with its performance. Lots of other people seem to be, so give it a go if you don't need a high performance NAS. It was one of the very first to come with a [linux firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSLU2#User_community), so [there's a thriving linux community around it](http://www.nslu2-linux.org/), and people have modified it to run varied things.

> There are two main replacement
>   firmware images available for the
>   device: the first is Unslung which is
>   based on the official Linksys firmware
>   with some improvements and features
>   added. Optware packages are
>   available to expand functionality. The
>   other is SlugOS/BE (formerly
>   OpenSlug), which is based on the
>   OpenEmbedded framework. SlugOS/BE
>   allows users to re-flash the device
>   with a minimal Linux system including
>   an SSH server to allow remote access.
>   Once installed, the operating system
>   must be moved to an attached hard disk
>   due to the lack of space available on
>   the Flash memory. Once this has been
>   done, a wide range of additional
>   packages are available to be installed
>   from an Internet repository.
>
> It is also possible to run OpenWrt,
>   Debian, Gentoo, FreeBSD,
>   NetBSD, and Ubuntu on the
>   device.
>
> The ability to run an unrestricted
>   operating system on the device opens
>   up a whole new range of uses. Some
>   common uses are a web server, mail
>   server, DAAP server (iTunes), UPnP AV
>   MediaServers, BitTorrent client,
>   FreeSWITCH, asterisk PBX and
>   network router (with the attachment of
>   a USB network interface/USB modem).

I used to have it running with an Unslung firmware booting from a USB stick, but recently converted to running Debian off the attached USB hard drive.

The nslu2 makes no noise and draws minimal power.

Answer (score 1):

For the maximum flexibility you're really looking at a PC. For small and silent you could build a nas around an atom based mini-itx board then you could install your preferred flavour of linux.  Being lazy I'd go with ubuntu because of it's simplicity then install webmin so you can administer it over the network without having to have a keyboard and mouse attached.

Comment: It's probably not going to be the most power efficient option though, and setting up a fanless pc can be both tricky and expensive.

Comment: I agree it's not the cheapest option and probably won't be fanless but I think it will be difficult to go completely fanless and still have a system you can install a full distribution on. You could go the route of the Via systems such as those available from mini-itx.com some of which are fanless and not too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The CH3SNAS is not expensive and runs linux.
http://nas-tweaks.net/CH3SNAS

The device runs Debian: http://www.aroundmyroom.com/2009/03/23/ch3snas-debian-yes-its-possible-but-not-for-everyone/

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with the "[SLUG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSLU2)" a while back, flashed it with [Debian](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/nslu2/). No noise at all, a bit underpowered for my needs but certainly usable.

It seems discontinued though, maybe you can pick up one on ebay?

Comment: Damn, nagul beat me to it :-)

Comment: You can certainly buy it on Amazon in both US & UK, but I agree that I find it underpowered for my needs. However, it makes an excellent NAS if you aren't very demanding, and have time to tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but [Amahi](http://www.amahi.org) seems to be an interesting Linux based "home server" software product based on Fedora. I've considered installing it on my [Intel SS 4200](http://support.intel.co.jp/products/server/storage-systems/ss4200-ehw/ss4200-ehw-overview.htm).

Comment: Is it actually hardware?

Comment: My wording was probably wrong. I've corrected the wording.