# The best NAS Server

Tags: nas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are my options for a multi-Terabyte home NAS?](https://superuser.com/questions/6107/what-are-my-options-for-a-multi-terabyte-home-nas)

I have a dream last night.. All my files approachable from any computer in my house!!
And a guy say to me with a bored voice.. Buy a NAS my friend.. So ok! what is the best for you? I would like a NAS with web server to make a home page and file server.. Thanks a lot for response

Comment: duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user

Comment: another duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/6107/what-are-my-options-for-a-multi-terabyte-home-nas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got some old hardware around you could set yourself up a [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) box that works really well. You get a web interface and lots of other good features.

An alternative if you've got a bit of cash to spend would be a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/) which is a really awesome and easily expandable bit of kit.

Answer (score 0):

Nethgear makes a very accessable NAS solution for home users.  You should give this a shot.
Here is the link http://www.netgear.com/Products/Storage.aspx?for=All&gclid=CPn8uL258ZsCFcZM5QodhE-O_Q

Now if we are talking the best.... Dream Big! Dream NetApp!

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Home Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx) might be what you need if you've got an old PC lying around.  I just recently started playing with the webserver (IIS) on it along with the built in file sharing and it works well.  My machine is running headless and I just RDP into it.  It's pretty much Windows 2003 Server with different limits.  If you've got a dominantly Windows network, it would be a good choice.  Plus, drive expansion is only limited to your case size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do extremely low dollar NAS you can also take a look a Lacie NAS drives.  These are cheap and they work well enough to get most things done in a home environment.