# Home Network Storage recommendation

Tags: home-networking, nas, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any recommendations on a NAS for a home-super-user ?](https://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user)

I would love to buy a ethernet connected box that I can store a couple of hard disk in and have it appear as a network drive on my home network?  This would be accomplished preferably without having to install any software on a client machine.

I bought a networked one last year but it requires drivers for any machine that wants to use it which is not too bad, but the drivers are dodgy and prevent my machine from hibernating which is a disaster as I use hibernate a lot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user

Comment: Or here: http://superuser.com/questions/6107/what-are-my-options-for-a-multi-terabyte-home-nas

Comment: I think my request is differnt to those two.

Comment: In what way? (15 chars w00t)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/15240  Also very similar to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend buying one of these NAS drives.  They are usable across the network and will operate in stand alone mode just fine.  You can connect to this just like it is a network drive on another computer or server.  The best part is that if you need more space, just buy another one.  This is modular storage at its best.

[LACIE 1 TB network drive.](http://www.lacie.com/us/products/product.htm?pid=11089)

[image]