# Foolproof automated backup strategy?

Tags: macos, backup, automation

How can I ensure automated back-ups of all my data without manual intervention?

My data lives on a 160GB MacBook internal hard drive, three 500GB external hard drives, and a 500GB network attached storage device (DNS-323).

One of my 3 externals is a 500GB TimeMachine, but it can only hold 2 weeks worth of some of my data. I have to tell it to ignore my music, which is very important to me.

Comment: "Every day, man is making bigger and better fool-proof things, and every day, nature is making bigger and better fools. So far, I think nature is winning." --Albert Einstein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *foolproof* is a pretty lofty target, I would recommend sticking with a OSX's Time Machine feature, but replacing your NAS, Time Capsule, and other external drives with an [HP MediaSmart Server](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/mediasmart-server).

With current drive sizes, you can get 8+ TB of storage in the MediaSmart, and they have **full support for Time Machine backups**. They're fast, reliable, powerful, and a good value -- certainly a much better option than the Drobo for just about any home storage/NAS scenario I can think of.

There are a lot of other *great* reasons to go with one of these, too -- see more raves (from me and others) about them in these answers:

- [Any recommendations on a NAS for a home-super-user?](https://superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user/9186#9186)
- [What are my options for a multi-Terabyte home NAS?](https://superuser.com/questions/6107/what-are-my-options-for-a-multi-terabyte-home-nas/10364#10364)

Comment: Those look pretty awesome. They beat the pants off my DNS-323.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a stupid idea, but why not swap out the 500 GB time machine hard drive for a 2 TB hard drive?  That way, you wouldn't need to exclude your music.

Comment: I don't have a Time Capsule, just an external USB 2.0 harddrive. Works fine with Time Machine. Yeah, I guess 2 TB drives are a lot cheaper than they used to be.

Comment: On the downside, a non-RAID, non-Cloud backup can fail. 2 months ago my iPhoto Library became corrupted, and when I went to restore from external HDD backup, I found that it had a hardware failure. Hence my desire for something a little more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/), and a few cheap terabyte drives.  Mac users seem to love those things.

I've heard from Mac users that have used [BackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) successfully by putting terabytes of data up on the cloud.  I couldn't find a way to easily say only backup these folders, which was disappointing.  If a disaster happens they will mail you your data instead of having to download it all.

I use a combination of a local backup run nightly and [JungleDisk](http://www.jungledisk.com), but for that quantity of data it would be pricey.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies that offers cloud backup and cloud disaster recovery as a service. The best ones are those who keeps an updated version of your data all the time and when a disaster strikes - they immediately take action and replace the data on your site. This way, people who are browsing your data won't feel the downtime/other disasters. Where I work we have this service (we have our most sensitive data online and we can't have a downtime or a disaster without a backup plan). We use Cloudendure and we are very happy with their cloud services.

Comment: A `cloud backup` differs from `automatic backups` of local stuff. Your solution is: move everything on the cloud, where, however, 2.160TB of data, fully backup, are going to be quite expensive. There are less expensive solutions, locally.